# array, I/O file and standard deviation (c++)

Tags: c++

```
    double s_deviation(double data[],int cnt, double mean)
   {
      int i;
      double sum= 0;
      double sdeviation;
      double x;

    //x = mean(billy,a_size);

      for(i=0; i<cnt; i++)
      {    
         sum += ((data[i]) - (mean));
      } 

        sdeviation = sqrt(sum/((double)cnt));

      return sdeviation;
   }
```

When I cout the result from this function, it gave me NaN.
I tested the value of (mean) and data[i] using
return data[i] and return mean
they are valid.

when i replaced mean with an actual number, the operation returned a finite number.
but with mean as a variable, it produced NaH.
I can't see anything wrong with my code at the moment.

Again, I am sure mean, data are getting the right number based on those tests.

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'd guess that the value of `mean` is large relative to your data, so that some of the `((data[i]) - (mean))` values are negative, and so overall `sum` ends up being negative.

Then, when you try to compute `sqrt(sum/((double)cnt))`, you are taking the square root of a negative number, which results in complex number, which is not representable by a `double`.

However, the underlying problem is that your standard deviation algorithm is incorrect. You are supposed to sum the **squares** of the distances from the mean, not the distances themselves. Aside from making your computation correct, this also guarantees that `sum` is never negative, and so you can always get a real-valued square root.

Comment: yes you are correct. it was my fd's code, and i was tuoring him. hahaha thx, you notice that too... :) yeah

Answer (score 1):

I think You should have

```
for(i=0; i<cnt; i++)
{    
   sum += ((data[i]) - (mean)) * ((data[i]) - (mean));
}
```

In the version You have now sum should be 0, but due to some rounding errors it's most probably a small negative value.

Answer (score 0):

You're taking the sqrt of a negative number (most likely), and that's because you're using the wrong formula for standard deviation.

Standard dev is not the sqrt of the average of (val-mean), it's the sqrt of the average SQUARE of (val-mean).